# How come injection @Resource works outside the container?

Tags: java, web-services, dependency-injection, code-injection

I'm testing webservices in Java SE, and I see that @Resource does work, wasn't this true only within a Container ? or with CDI ? why does it work in SE also !?

```
@WebService
public class Teams {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;
}
```

I'm publishing using `Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9876/teams", new Teams());`

Comment: The web service container (JAX-WS) is a different story. DI annotations (not CDI) have been migrated to SE with version 1.6: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. JAX-WS is part of SE as well...

Answer (score 0):

Not true. Container will inject the instance of the resource on any EJB component.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html

Comment: it's not EJB. it's not a container. it's in pure JDK :) not JEE